# How to Assign Sequential Value to Each Row in a Group

Tags: mysql, sequence

I have a MySQL table with data for two groups (fruits and animals), and I need to assign a sequential value starting at 1 **within each group**

The initial state of the data is:

```
Fruit   Apple   NULL
Fruit   Orange  NULL
Fruit   Banana  NULL
Animal  Dog     NULL
Animal  Cat     NULL
Animal  Horse   NULL
```

The desired result is:

```
Fruit   Apple   1
Fruit   Orange  2
Fruit   Banana  3
Animal  Dog     1
Animal  Cat     2
Animal  Horse   3
```

(it doesn't matter if the results are alphabetized; only that there is a unique number starting at 1 within each group)

So far, I have been able to assign a sequential value to each row ACROSS THE WHOLE TABLE (i.e., ranging from 1 to 6), but I'd like to ask for guidance on how to reset the counter back to 1 when the group changes from "fruit" to "animal"

Here is the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE TempData (GroupName VARCHAR(16), ItemName VARCHAR(16), Sequence INT );
INSERT INTO TempData VALUES ('Fruit','Apple',NULL), ('Fruit','Orange',NULL), ('Fruit','Banana',NULL), ('Animal','Dog',NULL), ('Animal','Cat',NULL), ('Animal','Horse',NULL);
```

And here is my current script

```
UPDATE TempData
INNER JOIN (  SELECT GroupName, ItemName, (@RowOrder := @RowOrder + 1) NewValue 
              FROM TempData
              INNER JOIN (SELECT @RowOrder := 0) VariableSet ) RowSequencing ON TempData.GroupName = RowSequencing.GroupName AND TempData.ItemName = RowSequencing.ItemName
SET TempData.Sequence = RowSequencing.NewValue;
```

Any help in detecting when the group name changes such that assigned sequence number starts back at 1 would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `ROW_NUMBER()` if you are running MySQL 8+:

```sql
SELECT GroupName, ItemName,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY ItemName) Sequence
FROM TempData
ORDER BY GroupName, ItemName;
```

I would also suggest *not* saving the sequence in an actual table column.  This is because the sequence will logically change every time data is added or deleted, which might force you to update again.

If you *must* do the update, then we can use an update join:

```sql
UPDATE TempData t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT GroupName, ItemName,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY ItemName) rn
    FROM TempData
) t2
    ON t2.GroupName = t1.GroupName AND
       t2.ItemName = t1.ItemName
SET
    t1.Sequence = t2.rn;
```

Comment: this works great, thank you very much. (I am on MySQL 8.0.28). Unfortunately, I have a business requirement to store the sequential value, but conceptually what you say makes perfect sense. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: I have given you an update option if you need it.